# Cannot click Google 1 button on my site

Tags: javascript

I just created a website for a new business that I will run, I try to set the Google 1 button, however even if it's correctly displayed I cannot click it. Does anyone know something about this problem?

Feel free to check the page http://mini-site.ca.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    (function() { 
        var po = document.createElement('script'); 
        po.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        po.async = true; 
        po.src = 'apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';; 
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s); 
    })(); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit and add your code into the question rather than as a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit the "< fb:like **width="50"**..." (facebook tag for like / send buttons)

```
<fb:like href="http://www.mini-site.ca" send="true" layout="box_count" width="50" show_faces="true" font="arial" class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget">
```

Like this.